# ES Sink connector debezium stops with error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

To understand how cdc works,
I have been working with the following eaxmple given at debezium site https://debezium.io/blog/2018/03/08/creating-ddd-aggregates-with-debezium-and-kafka-streams/.

In this if i try to change the sink connector from mongo db to elastic search and then start the es-sink connector. Its shows the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
```

The **Mysql Debezium source connector** properties are this (Do ignore the correction url)

```
{
"name": "mysql-source",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "cdc",
    "database.password": "passwrod",
    "database.server.id": "1840514",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "table.whitelist": "inventory.customers,inventory.addresses",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false"
}
```

}

The elastic search sink connector is what used in this example
https://debezium.io/blog/2018/01/17/streaming-to-elasticsearch/

The **Elastic sink connector** properties are this (Do ignore the correction url)

```
{
"name": "elastic-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "product-cdc,final_ddd_aggregates,dbserver1.inventory.customers,dbserver1.inventory.addresses",
    "connection.url": "https://localhost:9243",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.key.field": "id",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "schema.ignore" : "true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
    "type.name":"final_ddd_aggregates"
}
```

}

Please assist me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration you need to do as the error message tells you, and set `schemas.enable=false`. Using the example from the article, instead of:

```
{
    "name": "mongodb-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "final_ddd_aggregates",
        "mongodb.connection.uri": "mongodb://mongodb:27017/inventory?w=1&journal=true",
        "mongodb.collection": "customers_with_addresses",
        "mongodb.document.id.strategy": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.id.strategy.FullKeyStrategy",
        "mongodb.delete.on.null.values": true
    }
}
```

you would have:

```
{
    "name": "mongodb-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "final_ddd_aggregates",
        "mongodb.connection.uri": "mongodb://mongodb:27017/inventory?w=1&journal=true",
        "mongodb.collection": "customers_with_addresses",
        "mongodb.document.id.strategy": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.id.strategy.FullKeyStrategy",
        "mongodb.delete.on.null.values": true,
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}
```

To understand more about converters etc see https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained and also http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect

Comment: Hey Robin, it seems who where misguided with the question, Actually mongodb sink connector correctly works as mentioned in the example.So there is no issue with mongodb sink it correctly works without the converters. The issue is with the elastic sink connector, which I am taking reference from other example.

Comment: Can you update your question with details of your source and sink connector configuration, and we can take it from there. My answer stands based on the error message you cite.

Comment: Hey @Robin As directed I have updated the question with the source and sink properties, with dummy url connectors.

Comment: You have `"value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",` in your ES sink. You need to set it to `"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"` (see example in my current answer).

Answer (score 0):

as the error message implies you probably have JSON messages without schema stored in the topic you are reading from. You either need to enable it on the source side or disable on the sink side.

Please check this [FAQ entry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/faq.html#how-can-i-use-plain-json-data-with-kconnect) for mor details.

Comment: Can you brief me how can i disable this on sink side, as the topic source is the kstream code which is publishing it.